# Send a set<String> to FormParam

Tags: java, client-server

I want to send request to my server, which get a `FormParam("param2")` which is `Set<String>.`

I try to send a request like this:

```
param1=thing&param2=thing1;thing2
```

but it doesn't know this syntax. How can I sent it?

Comment: Can you please elaborate, little confusing as of now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the value as below,

`param1=thing&param2[]=thing1&param2[]=thing2`